# Does anyone make a push-push on/ pull-pull off bike pump?

Tags: pump

[image]Most current bike pumps require three hands to use - one to hold the tire, one to put the pump head on the valve and one to pull the lever back.  15 years ago, most bike pumps only required two hands to use because you could push the pump head on the valve and push the lever down with one hand and stabilize the bike with the other.  Does anyone know of anyone making this kind of old style bike pump?

Comment: Could you share some examples of the "three-hand" style pumps? I think that would help us think about alternatives for you. Also do you want a floor (track) pump or a frame pump (one that can mount on the bicycle)?

Comment: To those who are voting down a first post it would be very nice to say something about how it can be improved…

Comment: Sorry, but this is ridiculous, pumps are not designed to be used with three hands. Try: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how+to+use+a+bike+pump (edit: I think my vote & comment overlapped with your second comment dlu, I agree that downvoting with no comment is less than helpful, maybe question should be: how to use a bike pump).

Comment: You can buy replacement chucks if yours doesn't work, but likely you just do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

It does not take me three hands
[How to pump a tire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtsztWC-_8U)

One good reason for down to be the open position is storage, transportation, and longevity.  Most people would store in the down position.  For a frame mounted pump you definitely want to store / transport with the lever in down position.  For longevity of the rubber seal in the head it is better to store it in the open position.  You use force to close it but is must open itself.  Stored scrunched the rubber will lose elasticity faster than if stored in the open position.   Even if it goes brittle in open position you might still get one more pump out of it.

Answer (score 2):

For on the road, I use the [Topeak Road Morph G](http://www.topeak.com/products/Pumps/RoadMorphG). This pump has a hose, so it doesn't required that you hold the valve. It has a little tab that pulls out that you step on with your foot.  You can pump up a tire using one hand (and one foot) with this pump. You have a free hand to hold the wheel if you feel the need to hold the wheel while pumping. You can also use your free hand to hold the bike upright if you are just topping up the tire, and don't have something to lean the bike against and you don't want to lay the bike down on the ground.

The [Lezyne Micro Floor Drive](http://www.lezyne.com/product-hpumps-hp-microflrhp.php#.VcOgmrWX0cA) pump also works similarly and might also be a good choice, but it's not as easily mountable on the bike in my opinion.

Comment: Not talking about while pumping.  I am talking about the ease of attaching the pump head to the valve.  Old style ones were Push-push On and Pull pull Off.  New style ones are Push-Pull On and Pull-push off and are clumsy to use by comparison.  I have asked bike shop professionals to show me how they use new style pumps and it always involves some clumsy maneuvers that didn't used to be necessary.

Comment: Have a Lezyne.  Don't like it either.  Too much air escapes while screwing the pump head on the valve.  Best one I have is from prestalever but that only works with my nitrogen tank that I use for my tubleless tires.

Comment: Yes.  I know how to use a bike pump.  I just think that the new style pumps are way more clumsy to use than the ones we had over 15 years ago when suddenly, all pump manufacturers switched to a push-pull on and Pull-push off lever on the pump head.

Answer (score 2):

The lever on SKS Multi Valve head works the way you are looking for. It comes standard on new SKS floor pumps and you can install one on pumps from other brands, too.

That being said, I have used what you call new style head for about ten years and never felt the need for a third hand. The benefit of the new style is that the lever's rest position is flush against the hose where it doesn't snag at anything.

Answer (score -1):

http://taggiopro.com/ Here ya go, One handed operation and not that expensive..

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We prefer answers on this site to be self-contained. Please explain a bit more about this product so that users may find it, or something similar, if this link dies. If you do not do so, it is likely to be downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted. Also, please not that if you are in any way affiliated with this product, [you must declare](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) your affiliation within your answer.